# Checking existing values in database at the same time

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables: CB and Obj

```
            CB

   CBID    CharaID    Key Part
    1         1           1
    1         2           1
    1         3           0
    1         4           0
    1         5           1

                Obj

ObjID   CharaID   CharaValue
1          1      TestOne
2          2      TestTwo
3          3      TestThree
4          4      TestFour
5          5      TestFive
```

And I have two parameters that are send through c#.
@CBID and @CharaValue.

I need to join these two tables through CharaID column.
In table CB there is column Key part. When the value is 1 I need to check IF there is a same value that is send trough the two parameters with the values in the CharaValue column.

Example:
@CBID and @CharaValue send values for CharaID = 1 are 1 and TestOne and for CharaID = 2 are 2 and TestTwo. They both have Key Part 1 and I need to check if there is allready duplicate string values in Obj table, CharaValue column, bouth at the same time.

Can someone help me with the stored procedure to do this ?
I created some part but I need the rest...

```
@CBID int,
@CharaValue nvarchar(50)

SELECT a.CharaID, b.CharaValue
FROM CB AS A,
INNER JOIN Obj AS B ON a.CharaID = b.CharaID
WHERE "Key Part" = 1...
```

Comment: You've obviously put some time into this, but I'm afraid I just don't quite understand what you're trying to do. Maybe you could provide two or three sample sets of parameters, along with what you would like for output from each set?

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I find some other was to do this. This was to chaotic :/